# Adding https to a graphql express endpoint proxied by webpack

Tags: javascript, express, https, webpack, graphql

I'm building an app with webpack, express, and graphql. Express serves the express-graphql endpoint, which then gets proxied by webpack-dev-server. I am wondering how to add https to that endpoint.

I don't have experience with ssl and limited experience with express and webpack. I'm not even sure if the question is how to secure the proxy, the express server, or the express-graphql endpoint.

As a side note, I've also added user authentication with auth0, which seems to be working fine.

#### server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import graphQLHTTP from 'express-graphql';
import jwt from 'express-jwt';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import WebpackDevServer from 'webpack-dev-server';
import {Schema} from './data/schema';

const APP_PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const GRAPHQL_PORT = 8080;
const AUTH0_ID = process.env.AUTH0_ID;
const AUTH0_SECRET = process.env.AUTH0_SECRET;

const authenticate = jwt({
  secret: new Buffer(AUTH0_SECRET, 'base64'),
  audience: AUTH0_ID,
});

// Expose a GraphQL endpoint
const graphQLServer = express();
graphQLServer.use('/', authenticate, graphQLHTTP(request => ({
  graphiql: true,
  pretty: true,
  schema: Schema,
  rootValue: { user: request.user },
})));
graphQLServer.listen(GRAPHQL_PORT, () => console.log(
  `GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`
));

// Serve the Relay app
...

const app = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
  contentBase: '/public/',
  proxy: {'/graphql': `http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}`},
  publicPath: '/app/',
  stats: {colors: true, chunks: false},
});

// Handle incoming routes
app.use('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
});

app.listen(APP_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App is now running on http://localhost:${APP_PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to secure whichever endpoint is public facing. Using webpack dev server in production is not a recommended approach, but if you do need to use https then webpack dev server does provide [support for doing so](http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#webpack-dev-server-cli).

Comment: Do you know if that option secures the proxy or just the output?

Comment: It would only be putting webpack dev server behind https, not the express server. To secure express, you'll need to check out the docs on how to do so for that, as well.

Comment: I've been trying to copy the examples from the docs. The weird thing here is that express-graphql takes the express server as a parameter and then webpack proxies that express-graphql server. So there are 3 different APIs and I don't know which one(s) needs ssl configuration.